# Best format to pack data for correlation determination?

Tags: python, csv, scipy, correlation

I'm using a Java program to extract some data points, and am planning on using `scipy` to determine the correlation coefficients. I plan on extracting the data into a csv-style file. How should I format each corresponding dataset, so that I can easily read it into `scipy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each dataset is a column and all the datasets combined to make a CSV. It get read as a 2D `array` by `numpy.genfromtxt()` and then call `numpy.corrcoef()` to get correlation coefficients.

Note: you should also consider the same data layout, but using `pandas`. Read CSV into a `dataframe` by `pandas.read_csv()` and get the correlation coefficients by `.corr()`

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to further challenge you. If I have multiple sets of data, how can I break it up? I can insert "Subject1", "Subject2", etc. into my csv file.